# Total oxidation of toluene free enthalpy

Tags: experimental-chemistry, enthalpy

I have trouble finding whether this reaction is spontaneous or not :

$$\ce{C7H8 + 9O2 -> 7CO2 + 4 H2O}$$

I consider (from the CRC Handbook of Physics and Chemistry) :

[image: Enthalpy, entropy, specific heat]

And so I find :

$$\Delta_r H° = 7\cdot (-393.5)+4\cdot(-241.5) - 9\cdot0 - 1\cdot 50.5 = -3670 \;\text{kJ/mol}  $$

and

$$\Delta_rS°= 7\cdot213.8+4\cdot188.8-9\cdot205-1\cdot0= 406.8\;\text{J/mol/K}$$

So at T=298 K I have

$$\Delta_rG°=\Delta_rH° - T\Delta_rS° = -3670\cdot 10^3-298\cdot406.8= -3.8\; \text{MJ/mol}$$

This would mean the reaction is very spontaneous, but according to experimental data, it should not. (The reaction only occurs when heating and with a catalyst).

What did I get wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are trying to calculate a kinetic property (spontaneous versus nonspontaneous; on a compound level that’s inert versus reactive) with thermodynamic data (exergonic versus endergonic; on a compound level that’s stable versus unstable).

Thermodynamically, we should all be carbon dioxide and water, as should any other organic compound. However, the activation energy of combustion of organic compounds is rather large. Thus, while the reaction is *thermodynamically favourable,* it is *not spontaneous* in the absence of activation energy.

Comment: I think another way of saying this is that the kinetics of the reaction is very slow.